# What's the fastest way to upgrade multiple Pis?

Tags: raspbian

I have about 5 (I think) Raspberry Pis now and I was wondering how to upgrade them all without them all having to download every package.

Answer (score 6):

I found a quick way to upgrade multiple Pis is by first upgrading one pi.

1. Put in a USB flash and mount it:

   sudo mkdir -p /mnt/usb; sudo
      mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/usb)
2. `tar cf /mnt/usb/up.tar /var/cache/apt/archives`
3. `sudo umount /mnt/usb`
4. Insert USB flash in other Pis to be upgraded and mount it.
5. At the terminal type: `tar xf /mnt/usb/up.tar`
6. `cd var/cache/archives`
7. `sudo cp -n *.deb /var/cache/apt/archives`
8. `sudo apt-get upgrade`
9. `cd ..; rm -rf var`

Now the upgrade will already have all the files and it will not download anything making upgrades tons faster.

Comment: I removed the "community wiki" status here -- you don't have to use that. See: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki ).

Comment: Ah thanks; first time I've ever posted one that I answered

Comment: If you don't care about downloading, you could use multiple SSH ( Pssh )

Comment: A more hands free approach could be to do this with rsync.  Sure you still have the network load, but at least it's entirely internal.  The speed from reading across the local network should be fairly similar to that of a USB drive.